# Form submit is not working post mode in the magento 2.4.5

Tags: phtml, magento2.4.5, get

I have phtml file which has submit.
I am going to submit with post mode.
But get mode is working continuously.
Why is the reason?

```
<form id="publication_reg_frm" method="POST" action="<?= $block->getUrl('customers/mypage/publicationcfrm'); ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
  <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="contents_block">
      <div class="pan">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that the form key is being properly validated on the server
  side. The line **getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>**
  is responsible for generating the form key input field. Verify that
  the form key value is being validated on the server side when the
  form is submitted.
- Ensure that the URL **'customers/mypage/publicationcfrm'** is pointing to
  the correct controller action in your Magento application.
  Double-check that the corresponding controller and action exist and
  are properly handling the form submission.
- Check if there is any JavaScript code running on the page that might
  be interfering with the form submission. Make sure there are no
  JavaScript event handlers or functions modifying the form behavior or
  preventing the default form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<form id="publication_reg_frm" method="POST" action="customers/mypage/publicationcfrm" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="contents_block">
      <div class="pan">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```